# How to forcequit/kill in Unity?

Tags: unity, kill

Im using Unity and some application is hanging up. A sub screen from the install printer program. As in I have no idea what program, window. In gnome, and mate, there is the force quit applet. I searched for it in the dash menu and nothing. How do unity users kill arbitrary crashed GUIs?

Comment: Usually I open a new terminal and use `xkill`

Comment: try `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: @Serg he wants to kill an application, not unity.

Comment: xkill is best. open a terminal, run the command `xkill` and left click the problem.

Comment: @Tim OK, gotcha. In that case , I'll suggest `pkill`

Comment: Yeah xkill does eaxctly what i want. I can make an applet for it. I dont think this is the same question as how to kill an application. the windowing system doesn't necessarily have a name easily identified in the list. Graphically, I can see it, and I know which one it is. That is a MASSIVE leap from having to search for what thing is hanging up, and or which application by PID or name might be calling the hanging window. I think my question makes it clear typing a bunch of BS isn't what i want to do, I want to point and click kill. The linked reference has no mention of how to do that.